# firebase datasnapshot control the children

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How I can control DataSnapshot children value when there is no child with if statement. For example,get message when there is no children

```
 protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    databaseOrders.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            personList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);
                personList.add(person);
            }
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            // use a linear layout manager
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(DetailActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

            personAdapter = new PersonAdapter(DetailActivity.this, personList);
            personAdapter.setClickListener(DetailActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(personAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you have to check the datasnapshot getValue() is not return `null`

```
if(datSnapshot.getValue()!=null){
       for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if(postSnapshot.getValue()!=null){
                Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);
                personList.add(person);}
            }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hasChildren](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#hasChildren) to detect `dataSnapshot` have children or not.
Like

```
if(!snapshot.hasChildren()){
    // snapshot has no children
}
```